# How to verify Navcontroller.navigate() is invoked?

Tags: android, mockito

## Background

I am writing UI tests for Android Compose using Mockito. Upon testing navigation I experience a weird error message:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
navController.navigate(
    NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/SettingsScreenKey },
    null,
    null
);
-> at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1794)
Actual invocations have different arguments:
navController.navigate(
    NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/SettingsScreenKey },
    null,
    null
);
-> at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1794)

    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1794)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate$default(NavController.kt:1789)
    at com.trimble.ttm.networkdatausage.screens.MainActivityScreenTest.clicking_the_settings_button_tries_to_open_the_settings_page(MainActivityScreenTest.kt:148)
```

Notice that mockito claims the arguments are different while it explicitly shows that they are exactly the same.

## Code

The test (run with AndroidJUnit4::class):

```
@Before
    fun setupMainScreen() {
        context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
        appDataViewModel = FakeAppDataViewModel()
        mockNavController = mock(NavController::class.java)
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            MainActivityScreen(
                appDataViewModel = appDataViewModel,
                navController = mockNavController
            )
        }
   }
    
   @Test
   fun clicking_the_settings_button_tries_to_open_the_settings_page() {
       composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag(Constants.SETTINGS_ICON_TEST_TAG).performClick()
    
       verify(mockNavController).navigate(Constants.SETTINGS_SCREEN_KEY)
   }
```

The navigation invocation in app passed as a lambda into AppBar:

```
AppBar(icon = Icons.Filled.Settings) {                        
    navController.navigate(
        Constants.SETTINGS_SCREEN_KEY
    )
}
```

AppBar:

```
@Composable
fun AppBar(icon: ImageVector, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    TopAppBar(
        title = { Text(stringResource(R.string.app_bar_title)) },
        navigationIcon = null,
        actions =
        {
            IconButton(
                onClick = { onClick() },
                modifier = Modifier.testTag(Constants.MAIN_SCREEN_SETTINGS_ICON_TEST_TAG)
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = icon,
                    tint = colorResource(id = R.color.white),
                    contentDescription = null,
                )
            }
        }
    )
}
```

## Question

I am not sure where I am going wrong. The error message is very confusing. If there is not a clear solution to my current approach please suggest another way I could test that navigate() is invoked with the correct string argument.